# Making an html - table to match the design

Tags: html, html-table

I was trying to create the following table.  Could anyone help in figuring out what I did wrong?

Desired:

[image]

Current:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/EV5Yz/

Code:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=4>1</td>
        <td colspan=2>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td rowspan=4>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=6>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=6>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=6>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to be made:

- **4** - **8** need to be in row 2
- **4** should *not* have a `colspan=2` (it's no different than 5-8)
- Your `colspan=6` should all be `colspan=5`

http://jsfiddle.net/a7S6h/1/

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=4>1</td>
        <td colspan=5>2</td>
        <td rowspan=4>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=5>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=5>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EV5Yz/1/)**

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=4>1</td>
        <td colspan=5>2</td>

        <td rowspan=4>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=5>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=5>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <table width="100%" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="4" align="center">1</td>
        <td colspan="5" align="center">2</td>
        <td rowspan="4" align="center">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">4</td>
        <td align="center">5</td>
        <td align="center">6</td>
        <td align="center">7</td>
        <td align="center">8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5" align="center">9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5" align="center">10</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/EV5Yz/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=4>1</td>
    <td colspan=6 align="center">2</td>

    <td rowspan=4>3</td>
</tr>
<td colspan=2>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
<tr>
    <td colspan=6 align="center">9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan=6 align="center">10</td>
</tr>
```

[**check at fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EV5Yz/4/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :

```
    <table border=1 style="text-align:center;width:50%;">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=4>1</td>
        <td colspan=6>2</td>
        <td rowspan=4>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=6>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=6>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

One thing is make text align to center and give some width to your table.

Comment: This doesn't fix the actual layout problem.

Comment: I am sorry.. I misunderstood the question. My edited answer is working fine. check this now.